# How to show toaster from the promises in angular2

Tags: angular

Hello All I am facing some issue with promise and handling 500 internal server error I have created a Promises for handling post and get service but while 500 response is catched I am unable to show it in toaster here is my code.

```
var toasterService: ToasterService;

constructor(toasterService: ToasterService) {
  this.toasterService = toasterService;
}

postService(url: string, bodyParam: any): Promise < any > {
  return this.http
    .post(url, bodyParam, this.options)
    .toPromise()
    .then()
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise < any > {
  let toast;
  toast = {
    type: 'info',
    title: 'Data Zone',
    body: 'Data Zone Failure!',
    showCloseButton: boolean
  };
  this.toasterService.pop(toast);
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

But in this code

```
this.toasterService.pop(toast);
```

here are stacktrace

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toasterService' 
of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toasterService' of undefined
```

it shows this as undefined. What i am doing wrong and another thing how to show toaster in case of catch in promise.

Comment: full error code and html please.

Comment: In this statement `var toasterService: ToasterService;`  var is not required.

Comment: If you are using toaster in Service then it will not work ...because it shows on Component..try to use on particular component which  you want show toaster message

Comment: Have you provided the service in your app module, and imported it properly in your component?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set a variable for toastservice, bringing 'toastservice' in the constructor is enough to be able to refer to it with 'this'.

you will need to import http into your constructor also.

```
constructor(toasterService: ToasterService, http: HttpClient) { }

postService(url: string, bodyParam: any): Promise < any > {
   return this.http
      .post(url, bodyParam, this.options)
      .toPromise()
      .then()
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise < any > {
      let toast;
      toast = {
        type: 'info',
        title: 'Data Zone',
        body: 'Data Zone Failure!',
        showCloseButton: boolean
      };
      this.toasterService.pop(toast);
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

Comment: in handle Error (this.toasterService) (this) is undefined

Comment: What does the pop function look like inside of toasterservice

Comment: You may need to use (e) => this.handleError(e)